# While using Ganache in a web UI, how can I change address of user

Tags: addresses, ganache

While using Ganache in a web UI, I have assigned defalutAddress as a particular address.

But if I have to change user , do I have to always change defaultAddress in indx.html ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you do it dynamic, i.e. taking the address used in metamask while connecting it to ganache

Answer (score 0):

> You can connect metamask to your ganache and connect your website
> after running on the server to metamask. Then you can use dynamic
> accounts can access in your website.

[image]

> This is how I access accounts using metamask in the current
> development website.